# Registry find value, take key name then search and update another value

Tags: variables, batch-file, registry

No idea if title helps here, so i'll be as descriptive as i can.

I need to update the "Use this connection’s DNS Suffix in DNS registration" value for a certain Network card, i only know what the NIC Name ("NIC3-Networkname") is and it will be different on each server i touch.

I have identified the required steps, just not sure on how to handle step 2.

1) Query for "NIC3-Networkname"

```
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network" /f "NIC3-Networkname" /s
```

This then returns the following.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\{EFBE1796-C4F0-4612-B3D6-E94B794E84D4}\Connection Name REG_SZ NIC3-Networkname
```

2) Next i need to take the {EFBE1796-C4F0-4612-B3D6-E94B794E84D4} Key name, set it as a variable - lets say %NICUID%

3) Then need to take the above variable and add the DNS Name.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\%NICUID%" /f /v "Domain" /t REG_SZ /d "Company.com"
```

Any tips and advise welcomed!

Thanks
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the output of `reg` using `\` as separator and take the 7th token:

```
for /f "delims=\ tokens=7" %%a in (
    'reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network" /f "NIC3-Networkname" /s'
) do set NICUID=%%a
```

Comment: Cheers  Wox - I couldn't get it to work with Skip=2, changed to 1 (and tried to remove in another test) and it worked - any reason for that?

Comment: Updated. There was no need to skip anything thanks to `/s` switch, my bad.